# Fatal error: Call to undefined function escape() in load.php

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

For my site, I created a form to be filled by a participant for some training.

I started receiving this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function escape() in load.php on line 10
```

I have 2 php files that are included in HTML, load.php and disp.php

**disp.php**

```
<form method="post" name="FORMA" id="RTABLE">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
            <td class="Label">Ime i prezime:<span class="Red">*</span></td>
            <td class="Field"><input type="text" maxlength="200" name="ime_prezime" value="<?php echo $Error ? $Recover[ 'ime_prezime' ] : ""; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="Label">E-mail:<span class="Red">*</span></td>
            <td class="Field"><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="100" value="<?php echo $Error ? $Recover[ 'email' ] : ""; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="Label">Phone:<span class="Red">*</span></td>
            <td class="Field"><input type="text" name="telefon" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $Error ? $Recover[ 'telefon' ] : ""; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="Label">Faculty:<span class="Red">*</span></td>
            <td class="Field"><input type="text" name="fakultet" maxlength="100" value="<?php echo $Error ? $Recover[ 'fakultet' ] : ""; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="Label">Year of study:<span class="Red">*</span></td>
            <td class="Field">
                <select name="year" id="year">
                    <?php
                        $year = array (1,2,3,4,5);
                        for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $year ); $i++ ){
                            $year[ $i ] = htmlspecialchars( $year[ $i ] );
                            echo "<option value=" . $year[ $i ] . " " . ( $Error && $year[ $i ] == $Recover[ 'year' ] ? 'selected' : '' ) . ">" . $year[ $i ] . "</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="PRIJAVA" value="Prijavite se!" class="BUTTON" /><div style="font-size:11px">obavezna polja <span class="Red">*</span></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and **load.php**

```
<?php
$Added = false;
$Try = false;
$Error = false;
$ErrMsg = "";
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'PRIJAVA' ] ) ){
    try{
        $Try = true;

        $ImePrezime = escape( $_POST[ 'ime_prezime' ] );
        $Email = escape( $_POST[ 'email' ] );
        $Telefon = escape( $_POST[ 'telefon' ] );
        $Fakultet = escape( $_POST[ 'fakultet' ] );
        $year = escape( $_POST[ 'year' ] );


        if ( $ImePrezime == "" ) raiseError( 0x0F, "Morate uneti ime i prezime." );
        else if ( $Email == "" ) raiseError( 0x0F, "Morate uneti e-mail adresu." );
        else if ( strpos( $Email, '@' ) === false ) raiseError( 0x0F, "Uneli ste nevalidnu e-mail adresu." );
        else if ( $Telefon == "" ) raiseError( 0x0F, "Morate uneti kontakt telefon." );
        else if ( $Fakultet == "" ) raiseError( 0x0F, "Morate uneti fakultet." );
        else if ( $year == "" ) raiseError( 0x0F, "Morate uneti godinu studija." );

        //$rs = &dbexecute( "SELECT COUNT( id ) FROM jf_eric_prijava WHERE email = '{$Email}' AND naziv = '{$Trening}' and tip_prijave = 'Trening'" );

        if ( mysql_result( $rs, 0, 0 ) ) raiseError( 0x0F, "Vec ste prijavljeni za praksu." );

        dbexecute( "INSERT INTO jf_eric_prijava ( ime_prezime, email, telefon, fakultet, year) VALUES( '{$ImePrezime}', '{$Email}', '{$Telefon}', '{$Fakultet}', '{$year}' )" );
        $Added = true;
    }catch( Exception $Ex ){
        $ErrMsg = $Ex;
        $Error = true;
        foreach ( $_POST as $K => $P ){
            $Recover[ $K ] = htmlspecialchars( $P );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

There are Serbian strings, just wanted to give the original.

Comment: Where is your function `escape` defined? You may have removed that function and not the calls to it, or removed an included file which contained that function.

Comment: `escape` is not a built-in function in php, but it is a built-in function in javascript which is used to encode special characters with some exceptions.Instead you can go for `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: sorry for not clarifying. The function is defined and included.. Will try with mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0):

Is it just

> $email = escape( $_POST[ 'email' ] );

that you are getting the error with? Could try commenting that out and running the rest of it to see if you still get the error with the other statements. Might want to check your escape function itself, could be something wrong in there. Could post that if you are able, may help identify a problem.

Comment: The problem was with the escape function not returning the correct value..
it works fine now ^_^

Answer (score 0):

It is because of version of PHP
in newer versions "escape" is undefined
you'd better change the function and use prepare functions